# What are the issues with excessive tandem repeats in replication?

Tags: genetics, dna-replication

Why is it that tandem repeats like CAGCAGCAG cause primer-template misalignment and diseases like Huntingtons disease? By my understanding, too many such repeats can cause strands to form hairpins and loops that fail to be replicated in the template strand, causing deletions. Is this correct?

Comment: What research (see [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)) have you done to try to find the answer to this question yourself? You should be able to find it very easily on the internet.

Comment: Moreover, your question is unclear. Are you asking how these repeats increase or how they cause disease?